# IBAction of a UIButton is connected successfully but it doesn't get called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ibaction

The situation is:

I have a `UIButton` on the `.xib` file and I have its `IBOutlet`/`IBAction` connected correctly but when I click the button,the `IBAction` doesn't get called.

And then I added the code `[button addTarget:self action:@selector(onClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` manually, the IBAction works fine.

So what's wrong with the IBAction?

Comment: Show your IBAction method ? And have a look in xib it is connected only one IBAction or more.

Comment: Add pic of IBOutlet Connection.

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with XCode yesterday.Today I tried to reconnect the button to the IBAction method and then it works finally...